# Mac OSX Detecting When Finger on Magic Trackpad (Even if outside of window) Swift

Tags: swift, macos, touchesbegan

So my goal is simple. I am trying to make a program that detects when a finger is placed on the magic trackpad (preferably no mater what window they are currently on) to run a process.... Unfortunately things have not been going well. While I can detect a touch when the user taps in the window... as soon as it is outside of the window all bets are off.  Any ideas?

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.acceptsTouchEvents = true
        //self.view.acceptsFirstResponder = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    var count = 0
    override func touchesBeganWithEvent(event: NSEvent) {
        print(count)
        count += 1
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This sounds like something that would need to go through Assistive Devices.

Comment: You mean something attached via USB?

Comment: Could you trick a external magic mouse pad to work as something different?

Comment: No I mean through Universal Access / Accessibility

Comment: Is there a apple doc on this?

Comment: It's too late here in Chicago to write up a full answer for you. Check out [Monitoring Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH15-SW3) and combine it with Handling Trackpad Events

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure the touch events are supported by NSEvent monitors...

Comment: Apple seem to have restricted the global monitoring of touch events to its own usage such as in mission control.